# Install PEAR SOAP fails

Tags: php, macos, soap, xampp, pear

All,

I'm getting the following error attempting to use PEAR to install SOAP

```
    # pear install soap
    Failed to download pear/soap within preferred state "stable", latest release is 
version 0.12.0, stability "beta", use "channel://pear.php.net/soap-0.12.0" 
to install 
install failed
```

I'm looking for advice on what to do next. I'm running PHP 5 on a Mac using XAMPP.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
    # pear install soap-0.12.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Better is to use

```
$ pear install soap-beta
```

since you have to type less, and it still works when a new version is out.