# Failed to download pear/Archive_Zip within preferred state “stable”?

Tags: pear, php-extension, php-ziparchive

The server I am on is using Debian and I am trying to install Archive_Zip using pear. The command I used was:

`pear install -o Archive_Zip`

Then I got this error.

`Failed to download pear/Archive_Zip within preferred state "stable", latest release is version 0.1.2, stability "beta", use "channel://pear.php.net/Archive_Zip-0.1.2" to install`

I am pretty new to this. I just followed the commands from their(hosting) tutorial but I can tell from the error that I have to use another method to install the extension. Could anyone tell me how?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267474/install-pear-soap-fails: 

    $ pear install archive_zip-beta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run

```
$ pear install archive_zip-beta
```

because the Archive_Zip package is not stable yet.